# Java client throws overflow exception on c# server

Tags: java, c#

So I made a server c# and a client in c#, to expand usage I made a java client, but when I run the client it results in an overflow exception on the server for some reason, this is the code for the c# client(works flawlessly):

```
    private static TcpClient T = new TcpClient();
static byte[] SendData;
static X509Certificate2 Cert;
internal static string InitIIP(string Data, string proxyHost = "127.0.0.1", int proxyPort = 9050, string destHost = "ipalbloeis2gf4vo.onion", int destPort = 666)
{
    HttpProxyClient HPC = new HttpProxyClient();
    return "";
}
internal static string Init(string Data, string proxyHost = "127.0.0.1", int proxyPort = 9050, string destHost = "ipalbloeis2gf4vo.onion", int destPort = 666)
{
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("tor");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Hmmm, we couldnt see if a tor process is running, make sure it is otherwise server connection will fail, trying to continue.....");
    try
    {
        if (!T.Connected)
        {
            Socks5ProxyClient p = new Socks5ProxyClient();
            p.ProxyHost = proxyHost;
            p.ProxyPort = proxyPort;
            p.ProxyUserName = "";
            p.ProxyPassword = "";
            T = p.CreateConnection(destHost, destPort);
        }
        while (true)
        {
            SendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            NetworkStream serverStream = T.GetStream();
            buffer = new byte[4];
            buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(SendData.Length);
            serverStream.Write(buffer, 0, 4);
            serverStream.Flush();
            serverStream.Write(SendData, 0, SendData.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
            byte[] inbuffer = new byte[4];
            buffer = new byte[4];
            int readBytes = serverStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
            int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            byte[] bufferreader = new byte[MessageSize];
            readBytes = serverStream.Read(bufferreader, 0, MessageSize);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferreader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

and this is the same code but for my java client:

```
static Proxy tor = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9050));
private static Socket s = new Socket(tor);
static InetSocketAddress SERVERADDR = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("ipalbloeis2gf4vo.onion", 666);
static byte[] SendData;
public static String Do(String Data)
{
    try
    {
        if(!s.isConnected())
            s.connect(SERVERADDR);
        while(true)
        {
            SendData = Data.getBytes();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            DataOutputStream serverStream = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream serverInStream = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            buffer = new byte[4];
            buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(SendData.length);
            serverStream.write(buffer, 0, 4);
            serverStream.flush();
            serverStream.write(SendData, 0, SendData.length);
            serverStream.flush();
            buffer = new byte[4];
            int readBytes = serverInStream.read(buffer, 0, 4);
            int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            byte[] bufferreader = new byte[MessageSize];
            readBytes = serverInStream.read(bufferreader, 0, MessageSize);
            return new String(bufferreader);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Failed" + e.getMessage(), "Status", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return "ERR";
    }
}
```

And this is the function on the server that handles the client connections:

```
private void Do()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        requestCount = 0;
        Responder.Responder R = new Responder.Responder();
        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                //networkStream.AuthenticateAsServer(ServerCertificate.Servercertificate(), false, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
                buffer = new byte[4];
                int readBytes = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
                if (readBytes == 0)
                    break;
                int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0); //this throws the exception
                byte[] bufferreader = new byte[MessageSize];
                clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = MessageSize;
                readBytes = networkStream.Read(bufferreader, 0, MessageSize);
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(MessageSize));
                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferreader);
                byte[] outbuffer = new byte[4];
                serverResponse = R.Respond(dataFromClient, K, clientSocket);
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                outbuffer = new byte[4];
                outbuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Write(outbuffer, 0, 4);
                networkStream.Flush();
                clientSocket.SendBufferSize = sendBytes.Length;
                MessageBox.Show(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EndPointHandler.RemoveEndPoint(clientSocket);
                clientSocket.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("User Server >> " + ex.ToString());
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            }
        }
        EndPointHandler.RemoveEndPoint(clientSocket);
        Console.WriteLine("User Server >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(clNo) + " Stopped!");
    }
```

Exact Exception message: System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

I looked on google but was unable to find a fix for this

Comment: can you deduce from the Exception a more specific place in the code where the Exception is happening?

Comment: Endianness - I'll post an answer.

Comment: @mmcrae well sadly not, I only get it at "int MessageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);" when the client does: "serverStream.write(buffer, 0, 4);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possibly Endianness Problems

There's two mainstream ways of organising bytes; Little endian and big endian:

[image]

In short, you appear to be mixing the two. Java is big endian, .NET is *usually* little endian (as far as I'm aware, it doesn't strictly specify which it should be). When C# attempts to read the big endian number sent from Java, you'll end up with seemingly random numeric problems.

### To Fix it

Make sure you use the same endianness at both ends. A common technique to avoid it all together is send strings rather than raw integer bytes.

A rough example (C#):

```
// Little endian int -> bytes
public static void GetBytes(int value,byte[] result,int offset){
    result[offset]=(byte)value;
    result[offset+1]=(byte) (value>>8);
    result[offset+2]=(byte) (value>>16);
    result[offset+3]=(byte) (value>>24);
}

// Little endian bytes -> int
public static int ToInt32(byte[] data,int offset){
    return    ( (int) data[offset] ) | 
            ( ( (int) data[offset+1] ) << 8 ) | 
            ( ( (int) data[offset+2] ) << 16 ) | 
            ( ( (int) data[offset+3] ) << 24 );
}
```

As an extra side note, **your protocol is vulnerable** - I could crash your server by making it run out of memory pretty easily. Watch out for things like that if you're designing a custom protocol.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, but I send those raw bytes so the server knows how long the following query will be, as most queries in the application are of a random length, so while your answer does fix the problem, im wondering if there is any other way that I can let the server know the size of the message that is coming in?

Comment: @MatthiasHoste It depends on the messages - a protocol I use just starts with a 1 byte message type, then the type handler itself knows what bytes follow anyway; no explicit size required (i.e. it just reads straight from the stream). This also helps avoid that vulnerability.

Comment: Ended up changing your C# code for GetBytes to java and adding that instead of "buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(SendData.length);" So now: "GetBytes(SendData.length, buffer, 0);" and it works flawlessly, and thanks for the side note, guessing it's time to implement some security EDIT: just read your comment, noted it, thanks a lot :)